# Yii2 authorization via php and database?

Tags: yii2

Is it possible to split authorization such that items, item children, and rules use yii\rbac\PhpManager but assignments use yii\rbac\DbManager?

The use case for this is that items, item children, and rules (at least in my case) are controlled by the app and are essentially 100% static. The only time they will be updated is if new items are added to existing roles. Assignments, however, are tied to users and are very dynamic.

The idea is to keep the static items out of the database (thus not requiring migrations for updates) but still having dynamic items (assignments) stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can caching queries to items, item children, and rules tables.
In components section of config:

```
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
    'cache' => 'cache' //Here is your cache 
],
'cache' => [
    'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
],
```